# Row inserted but number not

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I trying to insert a row in codeigniter and row inserted.
Problem is all row inserted properly but in sql bighint(11) field inserted 0.
I checked properly in array value given.

```
$data = [
'sku' => $POST['rec1'],
'pruch_price' => $POST['rec2'],
'sell_price' => $POST['rec3']
];
$model->insert ($data);
```

Comment: use `$_POST['rec3'];`

Answer (score 0):

you should use $_POST[] instead of $POST.

But better yet, don't send $_POST directly to the models, instead use the post request provided by Codeigniter 4.

```
$data = [
    'sku' => $this->request->getPost('rec1'),
    'pruch_price' => $this->request->getPost('rec2'),
    'sell_price' => $this->request->getPost('rec3')
];
$model->insert($data);
```